# MVC Razor - How to return alert (Error or Success) Message from ActionResult and Remian in Same PartialView

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am opening a popup from Index Page as Follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink(ButtonName, "CreateNode", "Node", new { ID = value.ID, }, new { @class = "openCreateDialog", data_dialog_title = ButtonName })

$(".openCreateDialog").unbind('click').bind("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("<div></div>")
            .addClass("dialog")
            .attr("id", $(this))
            .appendTo("body")
            .dialog({
                title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                close: function () { $(this).remove(); },
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                height: 350,
                width: 560,
                left: 0,
                buttons: {
                    "Save": function () {
                        $(".btnSave").trigger('click');
                    },
                    "Close": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            })
            .load(this.href);
    });
```

From the above code i am opened a jquery popup.

In the popup i had the following code

```
using (Html.BeginForm("SaveData", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "NodeForm" }))
{
<input type="file" name="file"/>
<input type="text" name="text"/>
<input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Save" class="btnSave" style="display: none" />}
```

In the Home Controller i am saving the data as

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveData(FormCollection collections, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        try
        {
            string sourceFilePath = Path.Combine("c:/Test", Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
            file.SaveAs(sourceFilePath);
            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Here in the action controller if success i want to return "success" message or else return "failure" message with alert and remain in the same popup with data.

Comment: You'll have to ajax if you don't want the page to redirect/refresh.

Answer (score 1):

```
//ajax post request
$.ajax({
    url: "/SomeController/SendAjaxPost",
    data: { 'id': 1 },
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            if (data.Message) {
                alert(data.Message);
            }
        }
    }
});


//and Controller side c#
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SendAjaxPost(int id = 0)
        {
            string msg = "";
            if (id == 1)
            {
                //some logic here
                msg = "success";
            }
            else
            {
                msg = "failure";
            }

            return Json(new { Message = msg });
        }
```

//Or Second Example is:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveData", "Home", 
                       new AjaxOptions
                           {
                               UpdateTargetId = "TargetId",
                               HttpMethod = "post",
                               OnSuccess = "AnyOnCuccessMethod",
                               OnFailure = "AnyOnFailureMethod"
                           }, new {id = "ajaxForm"}))
{
    <div id="TargetId">
         <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </div>
}
```

You can call OnCuccess and OnFailure  event any javascript function

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Here i need to send FormCollection and HttpPostedFile too....

Comment: How can i send FormCollection and HttpPostedFileBase to the SaveData ActionContoller

Comment: You must add enctype = "multipart/form-data" if you want to send HttpPostedfile.
new { id = "ajaxForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

All input tag witch is inside the form send as formcollection. 
Vote me if i help you.

Comment: Hi George Bakuridze,

When i am not using script reference

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
i am getting HttpPostedFileBase and saving the file. but it didn't firing AjaxOptions "OnSuccess" script.

When i am using script refernce

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

I am getting HttpPostedFileBase  as null. but it firing AjaxOptions "OnSuccess" script.

Answer (score 0):

When i am not using script reference

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i am getting HttpPostedFileBase and saving the file. but it didn't firing AjaxOptions "OnSuccess" script.

When i am using script refernce

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am getting HttpPostedFileBase  as null. but it firing AjaxOptions "OnSuccess" script.

Answer (score 0):

When i am not using script reference

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i am getting HttpPostedFileBase and saving the file. but it didn't firing AjaxOptions "OnSuccess" script.

When i am using script refernce

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am getting HttpPostedFileBase  as null. but it firing AjaxOptions "OnSuccess" script.

Following is the code i am using.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnSuccess(data) {
    if (data) {
        if (data.Message) {
            alert(data.Message);
        }
    }
}

function OnFailure(response) {
    alert("OnFailure");
}
```

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveData", "Node", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "targetDiv", HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnFailure" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div id="targetDiv">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Save" class="btnSave" style="display: none" />
</div>
 }
```

And in the Controller i am using the following code.

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SendData(FormCollection col,HttpPostedFileBase   file)
    {
        string msg = "";
        if (id == 1)
        {
            //some logic here
            msg = "success";
        }
        else
        {
            msg = "failure";
        }

        return Json(new { Message = msg });
    }
```